# Access Denied with System Account in Central Admin

Tags: sharepoint

I have installed Sharepoint 2007 with Complete/Server Farm settings. When I supplied the credentials for the account in the configuration wizard (installer), I supplied another loal account (the name of the account) and the password. This is an admin account on the OS/Windows Server 2008, and is labelled as System Account in Sharepoint Central Admin.

I specified just the name of the account as it is local. Is this perhaps the cause of the error?

When I go Operations > Servers in Farm (in Topology) and select the current server, I get an access denied error (I am doing the admin tasks once the server is setup).

How can I resolve this? Do I need to setup AD?

Thanks

Comment: this question is better suited to ServerFault.com

Comment: Agreed, but since it is originally asked here let's try and answer it here? Developers have to cope with SharePoint Admin also and it is beneficial to have this info here where they can find it :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the account for Central Admin has to be the same as the farm account - check IIS and see what account is assigned to the application pool? If this is a dev machine, you do not need to setup AD and can use the same admin account for everything.

Comment: Hi, Sharepoint Central Admin has WIN-H54AGVCYSVK\SPAccount and OfficeServerApplicationPool has NetworkService (the other 2 pools are defaultAppPool and Classic .NET AppPool).

Comment: I tried making the Sharepoint Central Admin account NetworkService but when I went into Central Admin I got an IIS error (couldn't read config file).

Comment: Add the correct account (system) to the Central Admin application pool, recycle and try again.